# Is it safe to delete file in /var/log?

Tags: log

I noticed that my disk in my Linux ubuntu server is already full and one that's causing it is inside my `/var/log` folder.

I have these files inside my `/var/log`:

[image]

I don't know what files are these, but are these safe to delete?

There's a bunch of `alternatives.log.x` and other `.gz` files. Can i delete those?

Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to fix the symptom of a problem, rather than the real issue.  The logs will fill again, so why not look at what's in the logs first to see what's filling your logs.

Comment: yup, I agree with that and I can do that later but is it safe to delete these files?

Comment: Can you at least post samples (add to your question, please) of the current logs that are causing the most problems?

Comment: You're not listening to @guiverc advice. Figure out which log is taking up the space, then review the log to find out what's filling the log, then fix that first. In `terminal` type `cd /var/log` then `ls -alS` and look at the first 1-5 lines of output to see the top file sizes. Then `tail filename`. So NO, don't delete anything.

Comment: Agree that you need to figure out what is going on to create such big logs in the first place. Disagree that you shouldn't delete something in the meantime. If your disk is full, then the priority is to make a bit of room, then investigate. Delete the oldest files first. if this is a server, some services might no longer work properly (I recently filled by server disk by accident, and only noticed days later that a service (DHCPD) was no longer working properly). The answer to your question is, yes.

Comment: sorry boss  @heynnema for not listening!  I already followed guiverc advise, i just didn't came back here because it was Sunday yesterday, so you better edit your comment and remove that judgement of yours. I agree with Doug that the priority first is to delete old files first because investigating, because how can I investigate if my server is full and there are already live users, so i need a band aid solution first then investigate.

Comment: The oldest files may not be the culprit. It's usually the log file that is written to most recently, and that's why I gave you the `ls -alS` command, and instructions on what to do next. As any forensic detective will tell you, don't delete evidence without looking at it first.

Comment: @DougSmythies re: *"Delete the oldest files first."*... the oldest files may not be the culprit. It's usually the log file that is written to most recently. As any forensic detective will tell you, don't delete evidence without looking at it first.